# Is there a trick to the "Fists of Fury: Champion of Champions" fight?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I found the suggested levels for most quests in The Witcher 3 reasonable so far, but "Fists of Fury: Champion of Champions" has a suggested level of 11. I'm currently level 18 and beating my opponent would take ages based on the damage I can deal. With good footwork I can avoid all incoming damage, so this is not the issue, but the fight would probably take hours to complete. I am playing on Death March difficulty.

Am I missing something obvious here, like a trick or shortcut to win this fight, or is the level suggestion simply unreasonable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some tricks:

1. You can use consumables in this fight: so [Thunderbolt](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Enhanced_Thunderbolt) potion could help to boost your damage.
2. Your opponent in this fight is vulnerable to attacks from behind, for example check out [this video](https://youtu.be/yV289B0dWEc): the guy abuses this hard and wins in ~1 minute.